# Curlfileupload isn't using fullspeed

Tags: php, post, curl

Hi I have the following problem:

I have a PHP Script which uploads files via curl with a post. So basically it does hit the "upload file" button.

When I upload a 100mb file it takes roughly 100 secs (+/- 10). When I start a remote session and upload the same file with a browser it takes about 40 seconds with the upload script running in the background. So the browser upload isn't even at full speed.

My question is now: Why is the curl upload so much slower? I tried googling it and all i found were some mailings which affected an older curl version and windows machines.

PS: Server is running on debian, script is executed with the rootuser and nothing found in the php or apache configs.

@Edit:

The return of `curl_getinfo`

```
[url] => http://example.com
[content_type] => text/plain
[http_code] => 200
[header_size] => 344
[request_size] => 464
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 113.560758
[namelookup_time] => 0.000961
[connect_time] => 0.055728
[pretransfer_time] => 0.055896
[size_upload] => 105000463
[size_download] => 11
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 924619
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => 105000463
[starttransfer_time] => 1.057226
[redirect_time] => 0
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[primary_ip] => xx.xx.xx.xx
[primary_port] => 80
[local_ip] => xx.xx.xx.xx
[local_port] => 39679
[redirect_url] =>
```

Comment: Is the PHP script on the same computer as the browser you used to upload the file?

Comment: yep, both on the same machine

Comment: @Soundz, Try setting `CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, FALSE` and let us know the output. It is for debugging purpose on data transfers.

Comment: % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 26  100M    0     0   26 26.6M      0  1035k  0:01:38  0:00:26  0:01:12 1051k ---------it ranges somewhere between that value so its not really fast, the browser upload is roughly 3times larger

Comment: i get you guys the `curl_getinfo` array in a second... my slowpoke curl needs to finish the upload

Comment: @Soundz, Have you checked this `CURL_MAX_WRITE_SIZE` http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2012-05/0135.html

Comment: php doesnt offer `CURL_MAX_WRITE_SIZE ` as curlopt

Comment: I was checking out other sources and it says there is no fix yet. Better you open this question on bounty, experts may help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems this can only be resolved with a fix in curl.

This is what I did:

1. Changed my upload script to generate lock file if a file is about to upload
2. Opened multiple shells and executed the script

Or basically:

If the upload cant use fullspeed I upload so many files at the same time that the loss of speed is equaled.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't provided any code. I suggest you look through these cURL parameters. Your answer lies in here.

```
CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE
```

> If an upload exceeds this speed (counted in bytes per second) on
>   cumulative average during the transfer, the transfer will pause to
>   keep the average rate less than or equal to the parameter value.
>   Defaults to unlimited speed.

So i suggest you **enable** this parameter (which defaults to unlimited speed as mentioned)

Also, `CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME` & `CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT`

**[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)**

Comment: already checked it, since i never set any of those values the script should be set to unlimited speed

Comment: after setting all of those parameters, one time to false, the other time to numbers they wont reach the speed dropped even lower to an average of 550kbs-780kbs